# hybris mac hybris startup error coming all of a sudden

Tags: tomcat, sap-commerce-cloud, catalina

The moment I do `. ./hybrisserver.sh` after doing **ant all** (in platform folder)

or I do `. ./hybrisserver.sh debug`

I get the below error, how should I fix this. The setup was working earlier and I initialized it with a recipe. It works well if I give **./install.sh -r b2c_acc_plus start** in the installer folder

```
. ./hybrisserver.sh

dirname: illegal option -- b

usage: dirname path

-bash: cd: /tomcat/bin: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Inside Platform folder run `./hybrisserver.sh` instead `. ./hybrisserver.sh`

Comment: Steps would be
1. Go to `/bin/platform` 2. execute `. ./setantenv.sh` 3. now run `ant clean all` 4. Start the server using `./hybrisserver.sh`

Comment: i have to check yet

Comment: for some reason hybrisserver start does not work for this 1811 suite i have. what worked was hybrisserver debug

Answer (score 5):

It is happening because you are using **. ./hybrisserver.sh**

The solution is to use **./hybrisserver.sh**

Please let me know if you still face any issue.

Comment: Man... man... man.... wtf.... great answer man....  The setantenv I run with double dots and this with just one... very good thanks....